# HybridAuth w/ Google redirects badly in codeigniter-a3m

Tags: php, google-oauth, hybridauth, codeigniter-a3m

I'm using the [dev version (2.0) of A3M for CodeIgniter](https://github.com/donjakobo/A3M/tree/ci3-beta) to add secure authentication to my app. The auth process (which uses [HybridAuth 2.2.0-dev](https://github.com/hybridauth/hybridauth/tree/2.2.0)) seems to go well since the logs show:

```
(
    [hauth_return_to] => https://mywebsite.com/account/connect/Google
    [hauth_token] => uhas9b51ajhlehkbo1fehj79t0
    [hauth_time] => 1405629149
    [login_start] => https://mywebsite.com/account/connect_end?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1405629149
    [login_done] => https://mywebsite.com/account/connect_end?hauth.done=Google
)
```

But it redirects me to a page at this URL:

```
https://mywebsite.com/account/connect_end?hauth.start=Google&hauth.time=1405629255
```

with this content:

```
HybridAuth
Open Source Social Sign On PHP Library. 
hybridauth.sourceforge.net/
```

And does not complete login or account linking. I've tried changing my `redirect_uri` in the Google Developer Console to both `'/account/connect_end'` and `'/account/connect/Google'` with identical results. How can I get it to connect?

Comment: I recently tried using the PHP League library but failed -- see my other question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24807921/google-oauth-2-0-returns-400-bad-request-even-from-playground

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, although it looks like a configuration file problem or a bug, this is actually a problem with the URL handling in the web server. I added this rule to NGINX:

```
location / {

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 last;
    }
}
```